# If $A,G$ are dense in topological space $X$ and $G$ Is open, then $G\cap A$ is dense. Is it true if $G$ is not open?

Tags: general-topology

Prove:"If $A,G$ are dense in topological space $X$ and $G$ Is open, then $G\cap A$ is dense". Is it true if $G$ is not open?

I am not really looking for solution I need a hint to start solving these question.

Comment: You seem to be asking: "If $A$ and $G$ are dense in $X$, is $G\cap A$ dense in $X$"? (That is, dropping the assumption that $G$ is open). You were given answers to this, but you complain that the given $A$ is neither open nor closed, or that the given $G$ is neither open nor closed. *You did not ask for either of them to be open or closed*; in fact, you specifically asked for the case where $G$ is **not** open (and "not open" does not mean "closed"). Are you asking what you *actually* mean to ask?

Comment: uI fixed the question. I am not complaining, I just share. Thanks anywaysu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is open and dense, and $A$ is dense, consider $G\cap A$. To show $G\cap A$ is dense, you want to show that every nonempty open set intersects $G\cap A$ nontrivially.

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a nonempty open set. Now, we know that $\mathcal{O}\cap G$ is nonempty, because $G$ is dense. And since $G$ is open...

To see the hypothesis that $G$ is open is essential, as others have pointed out, just take $G=\mathbb{Q}$, $A=\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, and $X=\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Think about $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution.

The second part is not true in general. (if $G$ is not open)

Take for example $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology, let $$A=\mathbb Q, G=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$$
Obviously $A,G$ are dense in $\mathbb R$, but their intersection is empty, and therefore not dense.

Comment: Q is neither open nor closed

Comment: You asked whether or not the proposition is true when $G$ is not open. I answered it wasn't. You did not ask say anything about one of the sets being closed.

Comment: The first part is proving G intersect A is dense

Comment: The first part is a statement, not a question. I answered the only question in you post.

Comment: I fixed it.Sorry